# Bash globbing: how to express "something-*.txt except *-foobar.txt" as glob?

Tags: bash, wildcards

On the command line, can I express easily in terms of shell globs that I would like to catch all files `something-*.txt`, except for `something-*-foobar.txt`? If I can, how?

NB: I know how to achieve the same with `grep -v` or other combinations of multiple commands. The question is solely about whether (and if so how) to achieve this with shell globs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable `ksh`-style extended globbing with:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And then write `something-!(*-foobar).txt`

Comment: Thanks. Quick and concise. That seems to do the job nicely. Will it conflict with `dotglob`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L extglob *can* be affected by dotglob if your extglob is very general, such as `!(foo.txt)`. But if your dotglob is specific, as it is in this case, the dotglob won't matter.